# How to use streaming audio data from microphone for ASR in Qt

Tags: qt, audio, speech-recognition

I'm working on a speech recognition project and my program can recognize words from audio files. Now I need to work with the audio stream coming from microphone. I'm using QAudio for getting sound data from mic and QAudio has a function to start the process. This start(* QBuffer)  function writes the data into a QBuffer(inherited from QByteArray) object. When I'm not dealing with continuous stream, I can stop recording from mic anytime I want and copy the whole data from QBuffer into a QByteArray and I can do whatever I wanna do with the data. But in continuous stream QBuffer's size increases by time and becomes 100Mb in 15 mins.
So I need to use some kind of circular buffer but I can't figure out how to do that especially with this start(*QBuffer) function. I also avoid of cutting the streaming sound at a point where the speech continues.

What is the basic way to handle streaming audio data for speech recognition?
Is it possible to change the start(*QBuffer) function into start(*QByteArray) and make the function to overwrite on that QByteArray to build and circular buffer?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You've got the signatures wrong. It's `QAudioDevice::start(QIODevice*)`. It doesn't take a `QBuffer*`, although of course a `QBuffer` is a `QIODevice` so you could use one. You'd need a class that implements a FIFO on top of a `QIODevice`. It's high time the Qt folks added one to Qt, it'd be useful.

Answer (score 0):

boost.com is offering a circular buffer

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/libs/circular_buffer/doc/circular_buffer.html#briefexample

It should meet what you need

Alain